# How to get JETTY_BASE to work with Eclipse GWT project

Tags: eclipse, gwt, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a google web tool project that uses

```
serverHome = System.getProperty("jetty.base");
```

to build a file path. When I run this in Eclipse GWT Development mode, this is returning null which is breaking the file paths for the rest of my application. Is there any way to assign jetty.base or JETTY_BASE to my Google Web Tools project?

Comment: `-Djetty.base=war`? You could also use a separate Jetty server and use DevMode in `-noserver` mode.

Comment: `${jetty.home}` is the server home.  `${jetty.base}` is the instance configuration root directory.  what are you trying to do?